# how to write efficient event callback methods in javascript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I have a method that is being triggered by an `onmouseover` event. Every time it is triggered the method assesses and processes the items of a dynamic array. Is there a way to write the method so that if the `onmouseover` event is called again before the callback method is finished it will stop and start again rather than having to wait until it has finished before starting again?

Comment: please put some code. I think we don't know what the `callback`  you are meaning( AJAX request or Javascript event handler function ).

Comment: @calebboyd that is not true - you *can* interrupt JavaScript. See my answer.

Comment: If its just a case of your event firing too frequently, you can debounce the event handler. `$.debounce` or vanilla alternative. Otherwise a WebWorker might work well.

Comment: I would use $.debounce or _.debounce in this case probably, as @calebboyd mentioned

Comment: Debouncing doesn't interrupt the execution in progress, it just prevents running the handler too many times.

Comment: Yeah I don't want to use debounce. I was hoping to get efficiency by stopping the function from running before starting again. Would it be possible to have a global scope variable that the function periodically checks to see if it needs to return? If the function is running and I trigger another function with both functions run at the same time? Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: @McShaman no. Event calls don't run concurrently with other JavaScript. As I've told you, JavaScript is not a threaded language, and only exists within one single thread no matter how many event listeners there are. In order to achieve concurrent JavaScript, use a web worker like I said, or consider re-evaluating what code you have to circumvent these requirements at all.

Comment: So if I trigger the onmouseover event 600 times, javascript will queue up the function to run 600 times and I can't stop it once they have been queued?

Comment: That is correct, JavaScript will never run two code blocks at the same time on the DOM thread, this is a result of it being a single-threaded language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a drastically long process and / or large array, you might consider having the event trigger a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage). Basically it creates a separate JavaScript thread that can communicate with the DOM thread (the thread you almost exclusively use in JavaScript) via serialized data that can be subscribed to through event listeners on each thread. The advantage of this is that you can call `webWorker.terminate()` to immediately stop it no matter where it's reached.

Comment: Web Worker is cool but I think I'm looking for something with a little more support.

Comment: Well unless your process can be interrupted with asynchronous callbacks, you're going to be hard-pressed to "stop" in the middle of execution. Normal JavaScript isn't threaded.